# React state resets after change through socket

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, react-hooks

I am currently struggling with issues pertaining to socket.io and React. When the `socket.on()` is triggered i want to remove data from a state `const [data, setData] = useState([]);`.
The `useEffect` fills the data with a response from a rest api and works fine.
But when i try to remove some data from the array it changes it for a short time, render it and switches back to the state with the original api-data.

I check it in my remove function and try to remove it as follows:

```
const removeOrder = (order) => {
  console.log(data.filter(element => element[0] !== order.order_id).length); // debugging
  setData(data.filter(element => element[0] !== order.order_id));
};
```

The order is the message from the socket.io client.
I tried it inside the `useEfect()` and outside and nothing works.
Does anybody has an idea what to do?

Edit:
The `useEffect`:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = () => {
      setLoadData(true);
      axios
        .get(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_URL + "/order/book?type=sell")
        .then((response) => handleResponse(response.data.orders))
        .catch((exception) => console.error(exception))
        .finally(() => setLoadData(false));
    };

    if (data.length === 0 && socketActive === false) {
      loadData();
    }
  }, [data, socketActive]);
  
  const handleResponse = (response) => {
    let result = [];
    result = result.concat(
      response.map((prop) => {
        return [
          prop.order_id,
          prop.price.toString(),
          prop.max_amount_currency_to_trade,
          prop.min_amount_currency_to_trade,
          prop.max_volume_currency_to_pay + " €",
          prop.min_volume_currency_to_pay + " €",
          prop.trading_partner_information.username,
        ];
      })
    );
    setData(result);
  };
```

Edit2:

```html
const addOrder = (order) => {
    if (
      order.trading_pair === "btceur" &&
      order.order_type === "buy" &&
      (order.payment_option === "1" || order.payment_option === "3")
    ) {
      let response = [
        order.order_id,
        order.price.toString(),
        order.amount,
        order.min_amount,
        Number(order.volume).toFixed(2) + " €",
        Number(order.min_amount * order.price).toFixed(2) + " €",
        "not set through socket",
      ];
      if (data.includes(response) === false) {
        // response = data.concat(response);//[...data, ...response];
        let newData = [...data];
        newData[newData.length] = response;
        console.log(newData);
        setData(newData);
      }
    }
  };

  const socket = () => {
    const websocket = io("https://ws-mig.bitcoin.de:443/market", {
      path: "/socket.io/1",
    });
    websocket.on("connect", function () {
      setSocketActive(true);
    });
    websocket.on("remove_order", function (order) {
      // removeOrder(order);
    });
    websocket.on("add_order", function (order) {
      addOrder(order);
    });

    websocket.on("disconnect", function () {
      setSocketActive(false);
    });
  };

  if (socketActive === false && data.length !== 0) {
    socket();
  }
```

Comment: This looks correct for removing an element from an array. Is there some other code possibly adding it back in (via sockets/etc)? Data synchronicity issue between this component and the "source of truth"?

Comment: No, I have no other seen. It updates only via socket. Currently only remove, later also add. Also the `useEffect` wont change it. After initial loading, I add the code of the useEffect above.

Comment: I test it also with adding data. Exactly one data set is added and every following dataset overwrites the last added one.

Comment: It seems that the keys are not ignored when i add new data with `setData([...data, ...order])`

Comment: Ah, I see. What sort of array is `data` supposed to be? In your edit you create an array of arrays with the various values (which sort of explains the `element[0]` in the filtering), but in the comment above are you wanting a flat array of all the values, or instead of an array of values did you want an array of objects with these properties? Can you provide a more comprehensive component code example so we can better see how the state and lifecycle are working?

Comment: This is for mui tables. The structur is not my choice. If you want more, i take it from here:https://material-ui.com/components/tables/

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces your issue?

Comment: It is not possible to provide a complete reproducable Code exaample because parts of the used api a private and protected by Auth. But I try to show the websocket code which is an open api/socket.